# HELP! windows 7 lodaer corrupt/error

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2, 13.10, windows-7

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6724788

thats my summary after boot repair

so when i start the computer theres 4 choice or 5 i dont remember

ubuntu
windows 7 loader sda1
windows 7 loader sda 2
(something)

im trying to log into my windows.. but whenever i chose any of the 7 loader it just throw me to an error screen where i can press esc to restart the pc or enter to do nothing

please help i cannot get back to windows in this dual boot.
this is very very urgent

edit: for further details you can check my previous question here 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/402972/something-wrong-with-my-dual-boot-install-attempt

Comment: As per grub boot-loader entry Your windows 7 is under windows 7 loader sda 2 partition. Select this partition to boot windows.

Comment: i've chosen the sda 1 and it went error.. then i have chosen the sda 2 and it went error just the same.. help me

Comment: Try [repairing the GRUB](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows). Does that helps?

Comment: im sorry lucio i dont know hows that having anything to do with what happened to me but.. ill try it. wish me luck, i hope it didnt broke my computer even further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible your Windows 7 MBR has become corrupted. You can use a Windows 7 installation disk to recover it. Since this is outside of the scope of Ask Ubuntu, I'd refer you to Windows documentation to assist you further with the repair. It happened to me before with one of my computer builds and it's a simple fix.

Comment: thanks a lot ill look into it. i've been thinking that it might be the solution i was just confused on how am i supposed to get the windows 7 iso to create the live cd but ill manage somehow thanks for your help